# Typescript error in a Context for Firebase Auth: Argument of type 'User' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<User | null>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, react-context

I'm creating an AuthContext for my react app through firebase auth. I already tried the solution in [Argument of type 'User | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<User | null>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74596050/argument-of-type-user-null-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-setstatea/74597914#74597914). But it is throwing me the same error as follows:

Error on `setCurrentUser(firebaseUser);`

> Argument of type 'User' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<User | null>'.
> Type 'User' is missing the following properties from type 'User': linkAndRetrieveDataWithCredential, linkWithCredential, linkWithPhoneNumber, linkWithPopup, and 14 more.ts(2345)

Whole code:

```
import { auth } from '../utils/firebase'
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword, onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth'
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app"

// type firebaseUserType = firebase.User | null

const AuthContext = React.createContext<firebase.User | null>(null);

export function useAuth() {
  return useContext(AuthContext)
}

export function AuthProvider({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {

  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState<firebase.User | null>(null)


  function signup(email: string, password: string) {
    return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, firebaseUser => {
      if(firebaseUser){
        setCurrentUser(firebaseUser);
      }
    });

    return () => { 
      unsubscribe();
    }

  }, [])

  const value = {
    currentUser,
    signup
  }

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

It would be great if someone can point out where I am going wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `firebase.UserInfo` in `Context` and `useState` instead of `firebase.User`
Plus the return will be

```
return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={currentUser}>
        {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
)
```